# export query result as csv file with inner join in mysql

Tags: mysql, csv

Unable to query result as csv from mysql using GUI
when I click on export it jump to query window

Using **below query**

```
select a.product_id,a.model,b.name 
from oc_product a inner join oc_product_description b on
a.product_id=b.product_id where a.status=1
```

> I'm getting result to display but unable to export same as CSV file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
select a.product_id,a.model,b.name from oc_product a inner join oc_product_description b on a.product_id=b.product_id where a.status=1 INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/product.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```

you can export directly from sql.

Comment: #1 - Can't create/write to file '\tmp\product.csv' (Errcode: 2 "No such file or directory")

Comment: which os are you using?

Comment: it is just a path where file will be created.

Comment: give this path according to your os directory.

Comment: Window Server 2012 standard

Comment: I think tmp is default path

Comment: Static analysis:

11 errors were found during analysis.

Unrecognized keyword. (near "FIELDS" at position 169)
Unrecognized keyword. (near "TERMINATED" at position 176)
Unrecognized keyword. (near "BY" at position 187)
Unexpected token. (near "','" at position 190)
Unrecognized keyword. (near "ENCLOSED" at position 196)
Unrecognized keyword. (near "BY" at position 205)
Unexpected token. (near "'"'" at position 208)
Unrecognized keyword. (near "LINES" at position 213)
Unrecognized keyword. (near "TERMINATED" at position 219)

Comment: Unrecognized keyword. (near "BY" at position 230)
Unexpected token. (near "'\n'" at position 233)
SQL query: Documentation

select a.product_id,a.model,b.name from oc_product a inner join oc_product_description b on a.product_id=b.product_id where a.status=1 INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/product.csv' FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' ENCLOSED BY '"' LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'

MySQL said: Documentation

#1 - Can't create/write to file '\tmp\product.csv' (Errcode: 2 "No such file or directory")

Comment: Column name also required in this.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply make query in SQL tab, then press show all, then copy whole table contains columns and paste it to Excel or Open Office. Then You can save it as csv or any other file.